# How to intercept a click event and prevent inner element to receive it?

Tags: jquery

I've enclosed YouTube embedded code inside a div. The div id is **outer_viv**. I've make the size of the screen relatively small to make the video look like a thumbnail.

```
<div id = "outer_div">
 <h2>First Leader Aside</h2>
 <p>
    <iframe width="200" height="112" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myvideo"
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
 </p>
</div>
```

When the thumbnail is click, I don't want the video to start playing. I want to intercept the click, add a border to show that the video has been selected and display a bigger screen of the video in the main content section of the page.

How do I intercept the click event with jquery?

Comment: The scenario you are talking about is called event capturing that you want to stop. Jquery only support event bubbling not capturing for this you need to you javascrip `addeventlistener` method. Or better if you use plugins like fancybox or lighbox.

Comment: I've done a quick research on the `addeventlistener` and think it's what I want. At least, the `outer_div` is will get the click event. Is that mean that I don't have to worry about the iframe element getting the click event as well?

Comment: You need to write first event listener to stop event capturing for `outer_div` and another event listener for 'iframe` to stop event bubbling. By doing so both `outer_div` and `iframe` events won't collapse. This way you can write individual functionality for adding border using 'outer_div` event listener function and sizing your 'iframe' using iframe event listener function.

Comment: @RJ, event listener and stop propagation are new concetps for me. Is there a way you can provide some code that illustrate them, given the HTML I provided above?